# Undefined index: maxlength after update to 5.2.0

Tags: upgrade, error

I am relatively new to CiviCRM. After we updated to 5.2.0 I started getting this message when I enter the Create New Individual screen:

Notice: Undefined index: maxlength in CRM_Core_Form->addField() (line 1478 of /home/makernexuswiki/www/crm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php).

Searching Google and StackExchange I could not find any relevant info.

Did the upgrade fail to add a required index? Is this a big issue? Should I just set the system to ignore Notices?

We are on Drupal 7.5.9

Any help is appreciated.
Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jim,

This is a php notice, you can ignore. However this has been fixed in latest version of Civi. To fix this you can either

1. Apply fix from https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12090 or wait for next release.
2. Turn off php notices by navigating to Configurations >> Logging and errors. Set 'Error messages to display' to None.

HTH

Pradeep